# Get-Winevent, Filtering out server from being being scanned with a variable

Tags: powershell

I have a text file of a few dozen servers to scan their event logs. In a few cases I find that I get spammed with critical level errors that I have to pass off to someone else and during the time for another department to fix it, i want to filter that server out.

I wrote a function with people's help here and it mostly works. I can filter out the server I want to exclude, but if I try to run the script with no exclusions it doesn't work.

I've tried it without the -noserver option and using '' or "" for no server options along with "NULL" and then the script doesn't return any data at all when it's supposed to return hundreds of errors.

```
    function Check-Syslogs-v3
          {
           param([string] $box  
                ,[int] $eventtype
                ,[int] $daysback
                ,[string] $noserver)

          if ($daysback -ge 1)
          {


     $servers = Get-Content -literalpath   "C:\temp\servers.txt" 
     $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(0 - $daysback)
     $log = ForEach ($box in $servers) 
            {Get-WinEvent  -computername $box -FilterHashTable @{logname = 
             "System"; level = $eventtype; starttime = $Date} |
                    Where-Object {($_.Id -ne "137" 
                   -and $_.Id -ne "8" 
                   -and  $_.MachineName -notmatch $noserver)} | 
    select-object @{n='HostName';e={($_.MachineName -split '\.')[0]}}, 
    timecreated,id, message}


          }
           else
               {
                Write-Warning "'$Daysback' is not enough days."
               }
        return $log

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better than collecting the logs from all servers and then filtering out messages from your excluded server, just skip the server entirely. I would also suggest using the `FilterXml` so that you can only return the event Id that you want rather than returning all events and then filtering out 8 and 137. I also moved your `If` statement to a `ValidateScript` statement, and allowed multiple event types.

```
function Check-Syslogs-v3
{
param([int[]] $eventtype
    ,[ValidateScript({$_ -ge 1})][int] $daysback
    ,[string] $noserver)

    $XMLFilter = '<QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="System">
        <Select Path="System">*[System[(Level={0}) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= {1}]]]</Select>
        <Suppress Path="System">*[System[(EventID=137 or EventID=8)]]</Suppress>
      </Query>
    </QueryList>' -f ($eventtype -join ' or Level='), ($daysback * 864000000000)
    $servers = Get-Content -literalpath   "C:\temp\servers.txt"
    If(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($noserver){$servers = $servers |?{$_ -notmatch $noserver}}
    $log = ForEach ($box in $servers) 
    {
        Get-WinEvent  -computername $box -FilterXml $XMLFilter | 
        select-object @{n='HostName';e={($_.MachineName -split '\.')[0]}}, timecreated,id, message
    }
    return $log
}
```

So to get all Critical, Warning, and Error entries for the last 3 days, and exclude the server named 'Server07' you would do:

```
$Logs = Check-Syslogs-v3 -eventtype 1,2,3 -daysback 3 -noserver Server07
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check that if `$noserver` is null, assign a value to it. In my testing, it works if I just assign a space to it:

```
      if(!$noserver)
      {$noserver = " "}
```

Another option would be to force that parameter to be mandatory, but that seems to be the opposite of what you want. Finally, you could assign a default value to `$noserver` such as below:

```
param([string] $box  
     ,[int] $eventtype
     ,[int] $daysback
     ,[string] $noserver = " ")
```