# Powershell Get-EventLog Multiple -Entrytype

Tags: powershell, event-log

Is it possible to have the Get-Eventlog to search for multiple entry types at the same time or exclude one entry type?  For example, in the application log, only show me those with an entry type of 'Error' and 'Warning' instead of writing out two separate scripts?

```
Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Warning -After '1/1/2018' -Message "*SOME TEXT HERE*"
Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Error -After '1/1/2018' -Message "*SOME TEXT HERE*"
```

Comment: Try `-EntryType Error,Warning`

Comment: -Entrytype accepts an array of strings.

Comment: Beyond the above comments, if you want to do more complex filtering you should look at the XMLFilter option. You can generate XML using the Event Viewer, and use it as a template in PowerShell to perform some pretty complex filters. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48330604/3245749).